# NiFi-1.0.0 - ExecuteSQL, Event Driven

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow which inserts some data into some tables. After I insert into a table some data, I send a signal and then ExecuteSQL runs an aggregation query on that table. The tables names are based on the files names.

The thing is that when ExecuteSQL runs the query, I only get a subset of the result. If I run the same query in database's console, I get a different number of rows returned.

Could this be a problem that has to do with the Event Driven Scheduling strategy ?

If ExecuteSQL is stopped, and I get the flowfile ( the signal ) in the queue of the ExecuteSQL, and then I start manually ExecuteSQL, I get back the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running multiple inserts (using PutSQL for example) and you wish to run ExecuteSQL only after all of them are finished, and the order in which they finish is not deterministic, you might try one of these two approaches:

- **MergeContent** - use a MergeContent processor after PutSQL, setting the Minimum Number of Entries and/or Max Bin Age to trigger when the inserts are finished.  You can route the merged relationship to ExecuteSQL.
- **MonitorActivity** - use a MonitorActivity processor to monitor the flow of output from PutSQL and trigger an inactive alert after a configured time period.  You would route the inactive relationship to ExecuteSQL to run the aggregate query.

Comment: I've tried to use MergeContent, but it will result in blocking nifi after a couple millions of flowfiles.

Comment: I have PriorityAttributePrioritizer on the queues, but as long as you don't wait for the packets to gather up in the queue, they will not be in order 100%, thus my processor is firing up the event a little to early and there are still files to be inserted in the db.

Comment: The thing is that if I used MonitorActivity, I could not differentiate the files. After a file is inserted, I need to run an aggregate query.

Comment: Would be great if I could write a custom prioritizer for the queues in nifi. For example, I'll extend the PriorityAttributePrioritizer to let a processor read from a queue after all the data in the queue is sorted (ascending, descending).

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to let millions of flowfiles stack up.  You might use a chain of MergeContent processors, each merging 1,000 or 10,000 at a time.

Comment: Can you differentiate the last file that should leave PutSQL before ExecuteSQL is run?  Would a RouteOnAttribute processor work for that?